# Why does $\|f\|_{\infty} \geq |f(0)| = 1$ imply norm minimizer is $\{f \in C([0,1]) : f(0)=1, |f(x)| \leq 1 \}$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Why does $\|f\|_{\infty} \geq |f(0)| = 1$ imply norm minimizer is $\{f \in C([0,1]) : f(0)=1, |f(x)| \leq 1 \}$?

Where we seek minimizer of $A= \{f \in C([0,1]) : f(0)=1\}$.

What confuses me is that while this says that the supremum of $f$ is greater than $1$, then why does this say that the minimizer is the set given. Surely the minimizer is in that set, but I'm not sure as to why it's proper to say that "this is the minimizer", since couldn't it be smaller than what given?

Comment: What are you trying to minimise exactly?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything to "Minimise the set $A$". $A$ is a fixed set. I'd guess you want to minimise some functional amongst elements of $A$.

Comment: You haven't defined any order on $A$ so your last comment makes no sense.

Comment: Are you just trying to minimise the norm?

Comment: @RhysSteele Yes, so the task is to find a thing that minimizes the norm. Now the solution also makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

In this answer I assume you are trying to minimise the $\sup$-norm over the set $A$.

You know that $\|f\|_\infty \geq 1$ for every $f \in A$. You also know that the constant function $1$ is in $A$ so there is an element $g$ of $A$ such that $\|g\|_\infty = 1$. This implies that the set of norm-minimal elements in $A$ is $$\{f \in A \mid \|f\|_\infty = 1\}.$$

This is exactly the set $\{f \in C([0,1]) \mid f(0) = 1, |f(x)| \leq 1 \text{ for all } x \in [0,1]\}$, as desired.

Comment: What does norm-minimal mean?

Comment: Here $f$ being norm-minimal in $A$, means that for all $g \in A$, $\|g\| \geq \|f\|$.